# HDMI to Component

Tags: components, tv, converter, hdmi

I'm trying to use my Raspberry PI with HDMI output to my older TV with component in.

[Raspberry PI](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) -> HDMI --> COMPONENT --> [TV](http://pastebin.com/Nh1HsJ6r)
*(tv specs in link)*

Is there any way to do this? The screen size is 32", which means that 1080p and similar won't matter anyway. Highly appreciating all help!

Comment: For Component you mean Composite?

Comment: Despite the fact that the Raspberry PI is somewhat design for hackers, this is really off-topic here. Simply put you are asking how to connect a computer with HDMI out to a TV that only has component in. This is a consumer electronic question.

Comment: If you just want it to work, use the composite video output (yellow 'phono' plug)

Comment: @Kellenjb I'm extremely bad at this sort of electronic problems, hence I didn't know where to place this question. I can't see why the PI would only be for hackers? Their goal is to make more people able to learn programming.

Comment: @Zar By "hackers" I don't mean it in the white versus black hacker sense, I mean it in the hobbyist wanting to hack around with things to learn how to program. We are about designing electronics, not telling you how to use consumer electronics. If you want a site to ask this, go support the consumer electronics proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33064/consumer-electronics?referrer=nuAsQkb6FnELmsS17ULV8A2

Comment: @Kellenjb Fair enough, I do realize that this question doesn't belong here. Thanks for all the answers. Supported the proposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a simple conversion.  HDMI is a digital signal, while component is analog.  There are [devices](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002WBOQPU) out there which will decode the digital stream and output the component signal, however, they will likely be close to the cost of your pi.

If you aren't worried about high-def signals, there is also a composite video RCA out available on the pi (but this would be standard def such as 480i).